# FHIR - 403 Insufficient Scopes Error when saving DocumentReference with C#

Tags: c#, hl7-fhir

Originally posted here on the [Oracle/Cerner forum](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/domain/open-developer-experience/category/millennium-platform), but it's been a week with no answers and I'm stuck and hoping someone here will see the problem. It's not specific to Cerner as FHIR is a bigger healthcare standard.

I have a system app with C#, using the Cerner server that requires authentication and it works great for reading and getting data. Now, I'm trying to add a document to a patient. I'm sure there is something simple that I'm doing wrong and appreciate any help.

Here's the request uri:

AbsoluteUri: "https://fhir-ehr-code.cerner.com/r4/ec2458f2-1e24-41c8-b71b-0e701af7583d/DocumentReference"

I get a fresh access token right before trying to save the file. These are my requested scopes:

```
request.AddParameter("scope", "system/Patient.read system/Patient.write system/DiagnosticReport.read system/DiagnosticReport.write system/Binary.read system/Binary.write system/Condition.read system/Encounter.read system/Encounter.write system/Location.read system/DocumentReference.read system/DocumentReference.write");
```

I copied the JSON below from [Cerner's R4 example here](https://fhir.cerner.com/millennium/r4/foundation/documents/document-reference/#example-2) and replaced a couple things like using a valid patient id and encounter id:

Here's my relevant code.

```
using HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/fhir+json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Prefer", "respond-async");

Uri uri = new Uri($"{_fhirSettings.FHIRServer}{_fhirSettings.ServerId}/DocumentReference");

string jsonPayload = @"{
""resourceType"": ""DocumentReference"",
""status"": ""current"",
""docStatus"": ""final"",
""type"": {
""coding"": [
{
""system"": ""https://fhir.cerner.com/ec2458f2-1e24-41c8-b71b-0e701af7583d/codeSet/72"",
""code"": ""2820507"",
""display"": ""Admission Note Physician"",
""userSelected"": true
}
],
""text"": ""Summary document""
},
""subject"": {
""reference"": ""Patient/12742418""
},
""content"": [
{
""attachment"": {
""contentType"": ""application/xml;charset=utf-8"",
""data"": ""PGh0bWw+Cjx0aXRsZT4gVGVzdCBEb2N1bWVudCA8L3RpdGxlPgoKRG9jdW1lbnQgY29udGVudCEKCjwvaHRtbD4="",
""title"": ""Height Weight Allergy Rule"",
""creation"": ""2024-01-29T21:02:04.000Z""
}
}
],
""context"": {
""encounter"": [
{
""reference"": ""Encounter/98001628""
}
],
""period"": {
""start"": ""2023-10-20T13:45:00.000Z"",
""end"": ""2023-10-21T13:45:00.000Z""
}
}
}";

var content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Those are your requested scopes, but what are the actual approved scopes for your access token? In other words, when you make the token call, what is listed in the `scope` key of the JSON response?

Comment: You are using a two step authentication.  Step 1 gets a token/cookies.  Step 2 you use the token to get data.  Is step 1 returning a 200 OK?  You are trying to get HL7 medical data which is xml.  You are using hl7-fhir which looks like it can use either xml or jason.  The example link is showing only json while your code has "application/xml".  I would check the status code being returned to see if you are getting either 200 or 201 (like code in link).  I do not see any xml in you data so I'm not sure why you are using "application/xml".

Comment: @jdweng, don't want to speak for the OP but the XML content-type is for the document being passed in (the DocumentReference resource), not for the overall API call. The overall API call's content-type is application/json, as shown in the next-to-last line of code.

Comment: @Ashavan : You are mixing up the HTTP Headers with the body data.  The jsonPayload is the body data.  I have no idea what the DocumentReference resource is.  DocumentReference is part of the route where a webpage is located.

Comment: @Ashavan - Great clue as to what scopes are granted. I checked the response and indeed, I don't have two of the requested scopes. I've added that into the Cerner forum question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible scopes that your access token could have are determined by the permitted scopes for your app in your app registration. Since you are requesting a certain set of scopes but not getting all of those from the token call, that's a sign that your app registration needs to be updated to include all the desired scopes.

You should log into the [Cerner Code Console](https://code-console.cerner.com) and go to My Applications. Open the applicable app and in the API Access section, verify you have all the needed scopes checked (or check the boxes if there are ones that need to be enabled). Not sure if there's a delay in the change rolling out to the sandbox, so you may want to wait a few hours if the change doesn't take effect quickly.